# Calculations based on Region and Cluster query SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've table like this:

```
Cluster | Region | Value | Volume
---------------------------------
 West   |   AA   |  7500 |   2
 West   |   AB   |  9000 |   1
 West   |   AC   |  2200 |   2
 West   |   AC   |  7200 |   3
```

Get sum of value and volume based on cluster, become value 25900 and volume 8. Get sum of value and volume based on region, become value (7500,9000,9400) and volume (2,1,5). Then value and volume based on region divided by value and volume based on cluster. Data should be like this:

```
Region | Growth Value | Growth Volume
-------------------------------------
  AA   |     29,0     |      25
  AB   |     34,7     |     12,5
  AC   |     36,3     |     62,5
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5a908/27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT
A."Region", round((A."Region_VALUE"*100/B."CLUSTER_VALUE"),2) AS GROWTH_VALUE, 
round((A."Region_VOLUME"*100/B."CLUSTER_VOLUME"),2) AS GROWTH_VOLUME
FROM
  ( SELECT "Region", SUM("Value") AS "Region_VALUE", SUM("Volume") AS "Region_VOLUME"
  FROM cals
  GROUP BY "Region" 
  ) A,
  ( SELECT SUM("Value") AS "CLUSTER_VALUE", SUM("Volume") AS "CLUSTER_VOLUME"
  FROM cals
  ) B;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try in my original case.

Answer (score 0):

We can try doing two separate aggregations, one at the cluster level and one at the region level.  Then join them and take the quotients you want to see.

```
WITH cluster AS (
    SELECT "Cluster", SUM("Value") AS c_value, SUM("Volume") AS c_volume
    FROM cals
    GROUP BY "Cluster"
),
region AS (
    SELECT "Cluster", "Region",
        SUM("Value") AS r_value, SUM("Volume") AS r_volume
    FROM cals
    GROUP BY "Cluster", "Region"
)

SELECT
    r."Region",
    r."Cluster",
    ROUND(100.0*r.r_value / c.c_value, 1) AS growth_value,
    ROUND(100.0*r.r_volume / c.c_volume, 1) AS growth_volume
FROM region r
INNER JOIN cluster c
    ON r."Cluster" = c."Cluster"
ORDER BY
    r."Region";
```

### Demo

Comment: In original case, the query is very much and will be made on scheduler. is there something simpler?
Thanks for your answer

Comment: @FadhelJMuhammad I don't see any way around two aggregations, but maybe you can tune my query using the right indices.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you need 1 direct query, see below. im not sure what is the data after comma `29,0` . You may modify from this to what you want after comma

```
    select cals."Region",
ROUND(100.0 * r."Value" / c."Value",1) as "Growth Value",
ROUND(100.0 * r."Volume" / c."Volume",1) as "Growth Volume"  
    from cals 
    inner join
    (select "Cluster",
    SUM("Value") as "Value",
    SUM("Volume") as "Volume"
    from cals 
    group by "Cluster") as c 
    on c."Cluster" = cals."Cluster"
    inner join
    (select "Region",
    SUM("Value") as "Value",
    SUM("Volume") as "Volume"
    from cals 
    group by "Region") as r
    on r."Region" = cals."Region"
    group by cals."Region",r."Value",c."Value",c."Volume",r."Volume"
```

result

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try in my original case.